# jQuery animations sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, gsap

My question has already been asked a million times, but yet I can't find an answer that satisfies my needs. What I need is a function allowing me to play animations sequentially.

I'm developping a website containing many CSS3 transitions and jQuery/jQueryUI animations. I have broken those animations into elementary standalone functions such as :

- slideUpSomething();
- fadeOutSomethingElse();
- showThisOtherDude();

Those functions could be anything :

- animationA();
- animationB();
- animationC();

Using callbacks or queues makes the code impossible to manage. And to be honest, I'm not good enough to control them now (planning on learning later though)...
Chaining seems impossible, since I'm animating different elements in different ways.
Using timers seems awful to me.

What I'm dreaming of is a function "animateSequentially(sequence)" working as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function animationA() {/*declaration*/}
    function animationB() {/*declaration*/}
    function animationC() {/*declaration*/}
    ...
    function animationZ() {/*declaration*/}

    function animateSequentially(sequence) {
        /* Here is the code I need */
    }

    $('#someButton').click(function(){
        animateSequentially(
            [animationA,
             animationB,
             animationC,
             ...       ,
             animationZ]
        );
    });
});
```

The requirements are as follows :

- animations A through Z should happen one AFTER another
- the array of animations can be of any length

Obviously, the way of coding it doesn't matter, I don't care whether I need to use an array or a trumpet, as long as it works without nesting callbacks for ages... Anyone can help me figure the trick ?

Alternatively, if you think I should code things differently, I'm open to any advice...

Kisses !

Comment: Maybe your animation functions should take the next animations in an array as argument and once its done, call the other animation, if array.length  = 0 or null, end of animations?

Comment: How aware are you of **[`TimelineMax`](http://greensock.com/timelinemax)** and **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)** in general? This is _exactly_ the kind of situation that makes a great case for **GSAP** products.

Comment: @Tahir Ahmed : never heard of GSAP, I'm currently taking a look at their website, seems to be an answer to my needs. If you have some time, I'd be glad to read a quick summary of how you would code it with GSAP in an answer. Willing to accept it as my answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here is the thing. I am going to start with a quick intro but will try to lead you to as many reading links as possible. And I will try to keep it all short.

**[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)** is a fantastic suite of tools that originally started back in the Flash glory days, and has since been brought into JavaScript world. There are 4 main products: **[TweenLite](http://greensock.com/tweenlite)**, **[TimelineLite](http://greensock.com/timelinelite)**, **[TimelineMax](http://greensock.com/timelinemax)** and **[TweenMax](http://greensock.com/tweenmax)** plus a [few more](http://greensock.com/products/).

I usually load up a [cdnjs link to TweenMax](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/gsap) in my projects because **TweenMax** contains all of the above.

There are many ways to do what you are trying to do in TweenMax, here is one of them:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
var duration = .4;
var timeline = new TimelineMax({ paused: true });
timeline.to(divs[0], duration, { y: 200, ease: Power4.easeOut });
timeline.addCallback(doSomething, duration, [], this);
timeline.to(divs[1], duration, { rotation: 180, ease: Power4.easeOut });
timeline.addCallback(doSomethingElse, duration * 2, [], this);
timeline.to(divs[2], duration, { opacity: 0, ease: Power4.easeOut });
timeline.addCallback(danceForMe, duration * 3, [], this);
timeline.to(divs[3], duration, { scale: 2, transformOrigin: '50% 0%', ease: Power4.easeOut });
timeline.addCallback(moveIt, duration * 4, [], this);
timeline.play();

function doSomething() { console.log('doSomething'); }
function doSomethingElse() { console.log('doSomethingElse'); }
function danceForMe() { console.log('danceForMe'); }
function moveIt() { console.log('moveIt'); }
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
div { float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
div:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #cc0; }
div:nth-child(even) { background-color: #0cc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.17.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

Above, I am using two out of the plethora of methods available i.e. the **[`.to()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/to/)** and **[`.addCallback()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/addCallback/)** methods.

There is so much more you can do with this tool. You will be amazed. I encourage you to explore.

Further reading:

- Getting Started with GSAP: [Link](http://greensock.com/get-started-js).
- Jump Start: GSAP JS: [Link](http://greensock.com/jump-start-js).
- Video: Sequence JavaScript Animations Like a Pro with GSAP's TimelineLite: [Link](http://greensock.com/sequence-video).
- Timeline Tip: Understanding the Position Parameter: [Link](http://greensock.com/position-parameter).
- Simple GreenSock Tutorial - Your first steps with GSAP: [Link](https://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-greensock-tutorial-your-first-steps-with-gsap/).
- GreenSock Cheat Sheet: [Link](https://ihatetomatoes.net/greensock-cheat-sheet/).
- Codepen demos: [Link](http://codepen.io/GreenSock/).

Hope you find this information useful.

Comment: @KLôN: Since you seemed mainly concerned about calling functions than actually animating anything, I have focused on the same in my answer (hence the usage of `.addCallback()` method). But if there is any specific animating needs you have, or you have any questions in general, ping me.

Comment: pretty much what I had figured while browsing for GSAP tutorials. Quick and efficient answer to my needs, with the added candy of increased animation potential once I get to understand GSAP. A big hug for you, I'm dancing for you right now ;-)

Comment: oh yes! you will be surprised by how much control this suite provides you in terms of animation and everything. And I am glad I could introduce you to this tool :) dance like you have never danced before :)

Comment: solves my "timeline" trouble, allows me to get rid of CSS transitions, allows me to get rid of jQueryUI, gives me a complete and clean control of my flexbox-based layout (that part took some effort though). You can't imagine how much you helped me there !

Comment: Yup. this is an amazing suite of tools. But there is more: **[DrawSVGPlugin](http://greensock.com/drawSVG)**, **[Draggable](http://greensock.com/draggable)**, **[ThrowProps](http://greensock.com/throwpropsplugin)** and **[more](http://greensock.com/products/)**. Happy for you :)

Answer (score 0):

So suggestion, you pass the array of animations as argument to your first animation and you pass it on.

```
function animationX(var anim){
   ...
   ...

   if(anim && anim.length > 0)
       anim.shift()(anim);
}
```

Comment: I think I'm not understanding what happens here (gotta improve my JS basics). What happens after you shift the array ? "(anim)" executes the new first element of the array ? ---> confused

Comment: shift is like pop(), but it returns the first element of the array and removes it from the array instead of the last one. So at the same time you take it out, you "execute it", thats why the "(anim)"; So it's like you're doing anymationA(anim) for instance. So basically you're executing the next animation with whats left of the array of animations. Eventually the array's length will be 0.

Comment: though i just realized, if the animation is async, it might not work, because it will throw the next animation without waiting. but i'll leave answer there for future suggestions or ideas.

Comment: thanks, and yes, I'm not sure whether this will make the animations run in sequence... I'm taking a look at GSAP right now, even though I dislike mobilizing new libraries for each new problem. Looks wonderful so far.