# Bottom to Top FadeIn for horizontally stacked blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I am using jQuery Animate method to show horizontally stacked DIV blocks in sequential manner.

http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/3DuTG/42/

**JavaScript:**

```
function fade(index) {
    $('.block-item').eq(index).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, function() {
        if (index < $('.block-item').length) {
            fade(index + 1);
        }
    })
}

fade(0);
```

Actual ask is to animate these blocks in bottom-up FadeIn manner like mixing fadeIn & slideUp.

is it possible to implement FadeIn effect in bottom up direction?

Second, Is there any way to overlap the animation? For example, second column animation starts when first column animation is 50% completed.

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: would you be interested in a solution utilising **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)** tools?

Comment: anyway, with **[`TweenMax`](http://greensock.com/tweenmax)**, it would have looked like this: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3DuTG/46/)**.

Comment: Tahir's answer is a great solution. I also highly recommend GSAP

Comment: @LokeshYadav: I also provided an answer recently with some of the basics in **GSAP** which can be found **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209926/jquery-animations-sequence/32211160#32211160)**. You may find it useful.