# Hangout, Evernote menu effects in dataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, gsap

So I have set of data in `jquery DataTables` plugin and what I am trying to achieve is a List of actions popup under one action control. For clear example I would like to give example of `Hangouts` and `Evernote` application which has that particular functionality and below image shows it:

[image: Example of Hangout and Evernote UI]

So left side of the image you can see hangout's **+** control which when clicked expands to a view which will be like right side of image i.e. with all other different actions and some **fade In from bottom right**

Below is what I am upto but the below solution is kind of typical because it will have CSS problem and that particular **fade In from bottom right** animation I wasn't able to achieve and at present I have kept just `fadeIn`.

For better understanding here is the **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/uuag2oh0/1/)** and what I am currently upto

If you click on any `+` of any row you can see an overlay and 2 more controls appended upwards. Now if you click on first row it will be appended but top control will be partially visible since it is `position:absolute` [`.appeartop`] in below `css` and `margin-top` has been given for both `edit` and `delete` controls.

**HTML**

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
td.details-control {
    background: url('resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
.appeartop
{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    z-index:100000;
}
.delete{
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    margin-top:-51px;
}
.edit{
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    margin-top:-102px;
}
.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    display:none;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /*dim the background*/
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click','.action',function(){ //onclick of action button
    if(!$(this).hasClass('opened'))
    {
        $(this).css('z-index','10000').addClass('opened').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-remove')
        $('.overlay').fadeIn("slow");//just fading in here
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).removeAttr('style').removeClass('opened').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-remove')
        $('.overlay').fadeOut("slow");
    }
    $(this).siblings('.controls').slideToggle();//and slidetoggle here
    
})

$('.overlay').on('click',function(){
    $(this).fadeOut("fast");
    $('.action.opened').removeAttr('style').removeClass('opened').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-remove')
    $.each($('.controls'),function(){
            if($(this).is(":visible"))
            {
                $(this).fadeOut("slow");
                return;
            }
    })
})


$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "aaData":testData,
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" },
            {
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": '<div class="controls appeartop"><button class="btn btn-info glyphicon edit glyphicon-edit"></button>'
                                  +'<button class="btn btn-danger delete glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></button>'
                                  +'</div>'
                                  +'<button class="btn btn-success action glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></button>'
            }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
});
```

So basically I have 2 problems here:

> **- How to position controls without they getting off-screen?**
>
> **- How to get animation from bottom right for the `.overlay`?**

Comment: are you willing to explore a new library? have you heard of **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)** and tried it? seems like a fun thing to do with **[TweenMax](http://greensock.com/tweenmax)** (i.e. one of the tools provided by GSAP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right. I have a created a jsFiddle for you which you can find **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/0t8v30sz/1/)**. Here are the details:

- I resorted to use **[TweenMax](http://greensock.com/tweenmax)**, one of the animation tools provided by **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)**, documentation of which can be found **[here](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/)**.
- I also created an `.overlay-container` element on top of your already existing `.overlay` element. Reason to be followed.
- Initially, I am setting a few CSS properties of both `.overlay-container` as well as `.overlay` elements using the **[`.set()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/set/)** method of **TweenMax**.
- The important ones are `borderRadius`, `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties on `.overlay` element and `overflow` property on `.overlay-container` element. That is the reason why I created the `.overlay-container` on top of `.overlay` i.e. to set the `overflow` to `hidden`.
- Upon clicking on `.action` element, `.overlay` element is animated by the use of **[`.fromTo()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/fromTo/)** (and **[`.to()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/to/)** method when fading out) and the main properties that are animating are: `autoAlpha`, `scaleX` and `scaleY`.
- Another thing to note here is that in order to position the circle to wherever the clicked `.action` element is, I used jQuery's **[`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)** method to get its position and set that to `.overlay` element just before fading in.
- The rest is pretty much the same code as yours.

***JavaScript:*** (trimmed down version, only showing the fade-in part)

```
...
TweenMax.set('.overlay-container', {
  position: 'absolute',
  overflow: 'hidden',
  width: $(document).width(),
  height: $(document).height()
});
TweenMax.fromTo('.overlay', duration, {
  autoAlpha: 0,
  top: $(this).offset().top,
  left: $(this).offset().left,
  xPercent: -50,
  yPercent: -50,
  scaleX: 0,
  scaleY: 0
}, {
  autoAlpha: 1,
  scaleX: 3,
  scaleY: 3,
  ease: easeInOut
});
...
```

Hope this helps.

***Update:***

- I encourage you to explore this amazing tool. All credit to the creators who built this. I posted a **[similar introductory answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209926/jquery-animations-sequence/32211160#32211160)** a few days ago that you may find useful re **GSAP**.
- Also, I modified the existing fiddle just a little bit more to correct the positioning of the `.overlay` element to start exactly from the centre of the clicked `.action` element. Modified fiddle can be found **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/0t8v30sz/5/)** and the modification itself is to be found on the lines: **486** and **487** of this updated fiddle.

Comment: Bingo!! Thanks alot @Tahir.. Its really an amazing piece of work.. :)

Comment: Sure buddy!! love to explore always and yea no doubt that I got information on a tool that I wasn't aware.. :)