# jQuery .animate() switch to GSAP TweenMax

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, gsap

I am working on a project that animates single words in quick succession with varying degrees of speed. I have built something quick and dirty using **jQuery**'s `.animate()` and callbacks to make this animation.

You can see an example here on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYadpm) and the code below too (pretty big).

I am wondering how I can convert this to using **GSAP**. Below is what I am currently working on as a replacement for jQuery's `.animate()` and also a Codepen of that version is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyGoLE):

```
TweenMax.staggerFromTo('.frame', 1, { opacity: 0, delay: 1 }, { opacity: 1, delay: 1 }, 1);
```

As you can see my GSAP version is not working correctly like my quick jQuery one.

You can also see that in my huge horrible jQuery file that I can easily amend speeds for each frame which is very important, so I'd need to be able to do this with the GSAP version too.

How could I do this?

***HTML:***

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script>
            var clickTag="";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ad-container">
             <div id="preloader">
                <!-- show something while the assets load -->
                <div id="preloader"></div>
             </div>
             <div id="ad-content" class="loading">
                <div id="para-1">
                    <div id="frame1" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>ANALYSING</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame2" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>complex</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame3" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>data</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame4" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>is</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame5" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>challenging.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame6" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>Especially</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame7" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>here</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame8" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>at</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame9" data-speed="slowPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>GCHQ.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame10" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>Sometimes</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame11" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>you</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame12" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>have</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame13" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>to</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame14" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>act</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame15" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>quickly</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame16" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>but</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame17" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>accurately.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame18" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>at</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame19" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>other</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame20" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>times,</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame21" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>you</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame22" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>get</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame23" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>to</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame24" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>spend</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame25" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>a</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame26" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>bit</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame27" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>more</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame28" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>time</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame29" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>on</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame30" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>things.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame31" data-speed="regPace" class="frame right">
                        <p>Sometimes</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame32" data-speed="regPace" class="frame right">
                        <p>you</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame33" data-speed="regPace" class="frame right">
                        <p>start</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame34" data-speed="regPace" class="frame right">
                        <p>to</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame35" data-speed="regPace" class="frame right">
                        <p>follow</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame36" data-speed="regPace" class="frame right">
                        <p>a</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame37" data-speed="regPace" class="frame right">
                        <p>line</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame38" data-speed="regPace" class="frame right">
                        <p>of</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame39" data-speed="regPace" class="frame right">
                        <p>thought</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame40" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>and</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame41" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>it</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame42" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>leads</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame43" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>to</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame44" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>a</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame45" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>dead</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="frame46" data-speed="regPace" class="frame left">
                        <p>end.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--<div id="frame1">  
                    <h1>Banner content</h1>                         
                </div>
                <div id="frame2" class="off">
                    <h1>Banner content 2</h1>
                </div>-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TimelineMax.min.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/easing/EasePack.min.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/plugins/AttrPlugin.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="lib/zepto.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.flashtalking.com/frameworks/js/api/2/9/html5API.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            container = myFT.$("#ad-container");
            myFT.applyClickTag(container, 1);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

***JavaScript:***

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var regPace = 400;
var fastPace = 200;
var slowPace = 700;
var pause = 1600;

var container = $('#ad-container'),
    content = $('#ad-content'),
    /*f1 = $('#frame1'),
    f2 = $('#frame2'),*/

    /*clickHandler = (function() {

    container.on( "click", function(event) {
            window.open( clickTag, "_blank" );
        });

    })(),*/

    ////////////////// READY ///////////////////

    bannerInit = function(){

        /// preload assets

        showBanner();
    },

    ////////////////// GET SET ///////////////////

    showBanner = function() {

        content.removeClass('loading');

        $('#preloader').addClass('off');

        anim();

    },

    ////////////////// GO ///////////////////

    anim = function(){


        // your animation stuff // GSAP or whatever

        /*$('#para-1 div').each(function(index,element){

            //var that = $(this);
            var speed = $(this).data('speed');
            if (speed == 'regPace') { pace = regPace};
            if (speed == 'fastPace') { pace = fastPace};
            if (speed == 'slowPace') { pace = slowPace};


            setTimeout(function(){ 

            console.log('the speed for '+index+': '+pace);

                $(element).animate({"opacity":"1",},0);

                $(element).delay(pace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
            },index * pace);
        });*/
        /*function doThis(){
            console.log('Paragraph 1 complete');    
        }
        doThis();*/

        $('#frame1').animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

            $('#frame1').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
            $('#frame2').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                $('#frame2').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame3').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame3').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame4').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame4').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame5').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame5').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame6').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame6').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame7').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame7').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame8').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame8').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame9').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame9').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame10').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame10').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
            $('#frame11').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                $('#frame11').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame12').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame12').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame13').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame13').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame14').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame14').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame15').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame15').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame16').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame16').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame17').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame17').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame18').delay(fastPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame18').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame19').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame19').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
            $('#frame20').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                $('#frame20').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame21').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame21').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame22').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame22').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame23').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame23').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame24').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame24').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame25').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame25').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame26').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame26').delay(slowPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame27').delay(slowPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame27').delay(slowPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame28').delay(slowPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame28').delay(slowPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
            $('#frame29').delay(slowPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                $('#frame29').delay(slowPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame30').delay(slowPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame30').delay(pause).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame31').delay(pause).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame31').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame32').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame32').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame33').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame33').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame34').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame34').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame35').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame35').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame36').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame36').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame37').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame37').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame38').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame38').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame39').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame39').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
            $('#frame40').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                $('#frame40').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame41').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame41').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame42').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame42').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame43').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame43').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame44').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame44').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame45').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame45').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);
                $('#frame46').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"1",},0,function(){

                    $('#frame46').delay(regPace).animate({"opacity":"0",},0);


});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});
});

        /*$('#frame1').show(2000,function(){
            $(this).hide(0);
            $('#frame2').show(2000,function(){
                $(this).hide(0);
                $('#frame3').show();
            });
            console.log('jello');
        });*/

     }; //// END ANIM /////

     bannerInit();


});
```

Comment: Your pens don't seem to be working?

Comment: Hi, just checked http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYadpm and http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyGoLE and both are working as expected. The second link I just pasted doesn't work as thats the one I'm trying to use with GSAP.

Comment: hmm but I only see a white screen with nothing in it? I see a few errors in the console as well mainly regarding `http://cdn.flashtalking.com/frameworks/js/api/2/9/html5API.js`, `http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/cbcde0fd5f9f9934a2dd57c38b184ed71443188911467/style.css` and `http://s.codepen.io/boomerang/cbcde0fd5f9f9934a2dd57c38b184ed71443188911467/script.js` files.

Comment: Hi, just made a few changes aren't getting any errors in console.log now. Could you check again please? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYadpm

Comment: I think it is the `html5API` that needs to be loaded in order to function the banner but this is the asset that fails to load here for me. Let me see if I can fix that somehow.

Comment: so there is some copy that appears and disappears, first on the left side and then some more copy on the right side in between the borders of the banner, right? Just confirming that this is what it needs to look like?

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I'm after. Although I do need to be able to adjust the speeds and pause on certain words as well as make some words flash(hide/show in quickly). You can see in my script file that I'm a couple of variables to control the speed of the transitions(using .delays()).

Comment: close enough? **[codepen](http://codepen.io/tah_med/full/ZbBzRq/)**.

Comment: How on Earth!! I'm going to take a look at your code over the weekend but thats pretty much it. Are you able to make it pause on 'THINGS' for about 1 second? I'll try with your code once I've taken a look. But otherwise looks really good. Thank you.

Comment: I will post it as an answer with detailed explanation over the weekend. That way, you will hopefully be able to tweak it on your own.

Comment: By the way, out of curiosity, how aware are you of GSAP? I mean, had you seen the basic syntax of a tween before? Did you know that there was this thing called TimelineMax available as part of the suite of tools from GSAP? Will help me answer better if I can gauge your level of understanding with GSAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, go have a read of one of my answers which **[introduces you to GSAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209926/jquery-animations-sequence/32211160#32211160)** with plenty of links for you to first go through if you haven't heard of or tried **GSAP** before.

Secondly, your Codepen doesn't really work in Chrome for me (45+, Macbook Pro) but it does in Firefox. Not really sure what is the reason but something about security I presume.

Anyway, your **jQuery**'s `animate()` calls were difficult to understand thanks to the callbacks-within-callbacks loops :) and I am not sure if there would have been a better way to do them even if we were to keep using `animate()`.

Having said that, the decision to do all the animations with **GSAP** has to be applauded :)

Codepen URL can be found **[here](http://codepen.io/tah_med/pen/ZbBzRq?editors=001)** and here is how the final **JavaScript** looks like:

```
var timeline = new TimelineMax({ paused: true });
var easeOut = Power2.easeOut;
var easeIn = Power2.easeIn;
var durationRegular = 0.2;
var durationSlow = 0.8;
var durationFast = 0.1;
var pauseLocation = 5;
var pauseInterval = 2;
var container = $('#ad-container'), content = $('#ad-content');
var bannerInit = function() { showBanner(); };
var showBanner = function() {
  content.removeClass('loading');
  $('#preloader').addClass('off');
  anim();
};
var anim = function() {
  var frames = $('.frame');
  var numFrames = frames.length;
  var dataSpeed = '';
  TweenMax.set(frames, { autoAlpha: 0 });
  timeline
    .to(frames[0], 1, { autoAlpha: 1, ease: easeOut })
    .to(frames[0], durationRegular, { autoAlpha: 0, ease: easeIn });
  for (var i = 1; i < numFrames; i += 1) {
    dataSpeed = $(frames[i]).data('speed');
    var duration = durationRegular;
    if (dataSpeed === 'slowPace') {
      duration = durationSlow;
    } else if (dataSpeed === 'fastPace') {
      duration = durationFast;
    }
    timeline
      .to(frames[i], duration, { autoAlpha: 1, ease: easeOut })
      .to(frames[i], duration, { autoAlpha: 0, ease: easeIn });
  }
  timeline.play();
  timeline.addPause(pauseLocation, onTimelinePaused);
};
var onTimelinePaused = function() {
  TweenMax.delayedCall(pauseInterval, function() {
    timeline.resume();
  });
};
//
bannerInit();
```

The main feature of GSAP that is being used here is called **[TimelineMax](https://greensock.com/timelinemax)**, documentation for which can be found **[here](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/)**.

Other notable features being used are:

- **[`.set()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/set/)** method of **[TweenMax](https://greensock.com/tweenmax)**.
- **[`.play()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/play/)** and **[`.resume()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/resume/)** methods of **TimelineMax**.
- **[`.addPause()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/addPause/)** method of **TimelineMax**.
- `autoAlpha` property, can be found within **[CSSPlugin](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/CSSPlugin/)**.
- `Power2` easings which can be found within **[Easing](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Easing/)** section of the documentation.

Let me know if you have queries.